# How can I constantly update my panel drawing while reading from the serial port using WxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using WxWidgets to create a form application in C++, I need to draw a graph while I recieve data from the serial port. How can this be done? My serial code is working fine. I just need to beable to constantly recieve serial data and update my graph.

I am new to event-driven programming and I am using codeblocks. Can I use an event to this? Is it possible to use while loops in an event, I tried this and the program crashes.

ThANKS.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to move your code dealing with the serial port to a separate thread and post events from it to the main thread to update the GUI.

Comment: but i do not know how to create another "thread" as you call it.

Comment: You need to read about writing multithreaded applications in C++, this is not something that can be explained in a single SO answer or comment.